# Are all these IF's and None's the best way to handle RE?

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to make my own, very simple program to check if the text string the user has copied can be considered a strong password, based on the regular exressions. In the program, I wanted a strong password to be considered to have at least 8 characters, at least one lower and one upper case character, and also at least one digit.

The code I wrote looks like this:

```
import re, pyperclip

# regex for password
regexEight = re.compile(r"\w{8,100}")   # regex for 8 char.
regexLower = re.compile(r'[a-z]')       # regex for lower.
regexUpper = re.compile(r"[A-Z]")       # regex for upper.
regexNum = re.compile(r"\d")            # regex for number.

# get text from paste
text = str(pyperclip.paste())

# see if text matches every regex.
mo = regexEight.search(text)
if mo != None:
    exit
else:
    print("Password to short.")

mo2 = regexLower.search(text)
if mo2 != None:
    exit
else:
    print("Password need to contain at least one lower case character.")

mo3 = regexUpper.search(text)
if mo3 != None:
    exit
else:
    print("Password need to contain at least on upper case character.")

mo4 = regexNum.search(text)
if mo4 != None:
    exit
else:
    print("Password need to contain at least one digit.")

# return this if every regex matches.
if mo or mo2 or mo3 or mo4 != None:
    print("You have a strong password.")
```

I'm a complete beginner at RE so I used None to see if the object was matching or not (if it matched it returned the particular password, if it didn't mo(1,2,3) = None). However, I kind of feel that this way is quite unusual, or at least I don't think that is how RE should be handled, so that is why I asked here.

Is there any way to make this code simpler? Or is this way quite OK for a program? In my opinion it feels like the code would be better without all the if's and the None's. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: A lateral approach would be to find the right regex invocation to check all of this in one go.

Comment: Put the regexes in a list and write a loop to check them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a decent general approach would be to create some structure which holds the regexes that you want to check and the corresponding error messages.

```
import re

tests = [
    (re.compile(r"\w{8,100}"), "Too short."),
    (re.compile(r"[a-z]"), "Add lowercase letter."),
    (re.compile(r"[A-Z]"), "Add uppercase letter."),
    (re.compile(r"\d"), "Add number.")
]

check = True
for regex, message in tests:
    if regex.search("example_password") is None:
        print(message)
        check = False

if check:
    print("Strong password.")
```

Comment: That made the code much simpler, without all those IFs. I was struggeling to get the for loop to work with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way more complex than it needs to be:

```
def validate_password(password):
    if not password or len(password) < 8:
        print("Password too short!")
    elif password == password.lower() or password == password.upper():
        print("Password must contain at least one lowercase and one uppercase character!")
    elif not any(c.isdigit() for c in password):
        print("Password must contain at least one digit!")
    else:
        return True  # all is well
    return False  # didn't validate
```

Comment: Thats a much more clean way to write it. However, I used RE because that was why I wrote the program from the beginning, to practice it. This code is very useful though, thank you.